# It takes a long time to find window using pywinauto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, pywinauto

I am trying to automate the handeling of multiple applications. 
I can open a seccond application from the first one. I need to select the second window in order to be able to opperate it.
I am currently able to do this, however the required time varies from 2 second to almost a minute. I know multiple factors influence this, like other progragramms running at the same time. Still I think the time which is required could be reduced by using a more efficient code.

I currently do this:

```
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia") 
app.connect(path="Document-I-wish-to-find.exe")
mywindows = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re=".*Firstpartofwindowname ")
app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(handle=mywindows[0])
```

Is it faster if I don't search for Title but something else ?
Or is there another method which I could use, with the same result ?

Comment: Which line takes so long time?

Comment: The 3th line of the code. The rest works realy fast.

Comment: It's a low level function we don't recommend to use directly. Adding top_level_only=True will make it much faster, as it usually called different way on various levels.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, from the explenation of the function I understood that top_level_only was default. Now I see I probably misinterpeted this. My goal is to intergrate this code in a loop, which inturn will be looped. Therfore every second will matter. Would adding more find criteria decrease the required time? Or is there another method I should use to go about this problem ? If so I would like to know what I should search for (keywords).

Comment: `class_name` or `control_type` will also speed it up.

Comment: This has helped a lot. The code can now find the window fast, even if I don't close other programms.

Comment: Great! Added as an answer with more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To speed it up use class_name keyword. It's faster because class_name can be obtained by 1 Win32 function call, while getting text requires sending 2 window messages to another process. pywinauto filters handles by class_name first, of course.